# How can I write code to add and remove functions from a script?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm in the process of giving the user the opportunity to add additional functions to an existing bash shell script.

### The existing script named .profile_app looks like this:

```
function start_app() {home/run.sh start}
function stop_app() {/home/run.sh stop}
```

### The user can extend the above script with the following script.

```
  read -p "Name of App" n1
  read -p "How to start" n2
  read -p "How to stop:" n3
            
  echo " function ${n1}_start() { $n2 }" >> /home/.profile_app
  echo " function ${n1}_stop() { $n3 }" >> /home/.profile_app
```

### After running this script, .profile_app would look like this.

```
function start_app() { home/run.sh start }
function stop_app() { home/run.sh stop }
    
function test_start() { /etc/init.d/test start }
function test_stop() { /etc/init.d/test stop}
```

Adding a new function is no problem at all. But how can I remove a function from this file? E.g. the last added 2 functions test_start and test_stop? What does the code for that look like?

### Addendum

I think I couldn't describe my problem correctly. The syntaxes are irrelevant in this case. The above scripts are just simplified examples from my actual code. They really work. My question is, what should the script be like if the user should be able to delete a function from the profile (instead of adding it). For example, the user enters that he would like to delete the test_start and test_Stop functions again.

Like

```
read -p "Name of App to be deleted" n1


delete "function test_start() { .... }" from .profile_app ???
delete "function test_stop() { .... }" from .profile_app ???
```

How do I do that with the script?

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but note that `function funcname() {` merges two different syntax forms, the legacy ksh `function funcname {` and the POSIX `funcname() {`, in a way that isn't compatible with _either_ legacy ksh or POSIX sh (and is thus gratuitously incompatible with ash/dash/posh/etc). See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete -- and consider just sticking to the POSIX syntax going forward when there's no specific advantage to be gained from deviating from the standard.

Comment: That said, I don't recommend trying to script adding/removing functions to a file _at all_. It's much saner to have a _directory_ where your code just adds new entries to that directory as separate files (and at runtime, every file gets sourced) -- then when you want to delete or replace something, you just delete or replace the individual file as a whole; far less error-prone than trying to script content-aware edits.

Comment: In the one-liner function form; the closing `}` **requires** a semicolon: `start_app() { home/run.sh start; }` -- see [3.2.4.3 Grouping Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping) in the manual

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following solution where you include files from a folder, one file per function. To de-/activate them, you would just place the respective file into that folder, or remove it.

*.profile_app*

```
for file in /path/to/profile/includes/* ; do
    source "${file}"
done
```

*/path/to/profile/includes/start_app.sh*

```
function start_app() {
    /path/to/home/run.sh start
}
```

*/path/to/profile/includes/stop_app.sh*

```
function stop_app() {
    /path/to/home/run.sh stop
}
```

PS: `bash` allows the `function` keyword, but it is not allowed by POSIX, and has no real function. I suggest to simply use:

```
stop_app() {
    /path/to/home/run.sh stop
}
```